# Charcter Glitches in Terraria Mobile

Tags: terraria-mobile

I was playing Terraria in the morning, and I took a break. When I came back, all my characters were being weird.

I originally had three characters. character1,character2, and Human. Human was completely deleted, character2 took the icon from character1, a new character option appeared with the icon from character2, and character1 appears with no icon at all.

It says that I made Human in a NEWER version?!?!?!? I have the MOST RECENT VERSION!!!! Please comment if you have had any simillar issues.

How do I fix THIS?!?

Comment: I mean, I ran out of power but what would that do?

Comment: That's why i stopped :)

Comment: why did someone edit this? ANYWAY they were all deleted just 1 skin was kept

Comment: direct thing it says when I get to charcters: The save file Human-1442877784.player(vo) was created with a newer version of Terraria and could not be loaded.

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: Plz help me I had guy with titanium armor

Comment: EVERTHING RELATED T CHARCTERS IS GONE!!!!

Comment: Calm down, Now, try uploading the remaining character to cloud, then delete the game and reinstall the game then sync the character to the device and play the game again.

Answer (score 0):

The newer version usually refers to backups of planets. The possibilities is either this is a glitch or bug. You should report the incident to re-logic as it seems multiple users have the same problem. back to my earlier statement if you have a preexisting backup you should attempt to play on that (don't make a backup to solve this problem for that will only complicate things probably). If that doesn't work the main trouble shooting tactics should prob be used, Uninstalling and re-download, re bring up your phone, and reset.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem.

What fixed it for me was to make a new character then delete it.